# how to create UNIX / Linux commands?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm looking to create my own Unix/ Linux commands using C programming.
Say for example .. I wrote simple file copy program, I'd like to make it as a Unix/ Linux command.

How do I do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "make it as a command"?

Comment: If you mean be able to run it in from any arbitrary directory, you will need to put it, a copy of it, or a symlink to it in a directory in your path (or change your path to include it's directory).  `echo $PATH` will tell you what directories into which you can place it (or a copy, etc.) and be able to run it from anywhere.

Comment: As the [faq#dontask] says, "If you can imagine an _entire book_ that answers your question, you’re asking too much."  There are dozens of books about programming for Unix and Linux systems.

Comment: What I'm exactly looking for is... 
say a command "foo". I should be able to execute a specific task which I write by entering "foo" in terminal.

Comment: Create a program that does what you want, compile it to an executable named "foo", and then do one of the following: a) copy the executable to `/usr/local/bin`; b) create a *symbolic link* to the executable and save the link to `/usr/local/bin`; c) add the directory where the `foo` executable lives to your PATH.  There's nothing magic about Unix/linux commands; they're just plain executable files.  Now, if you're asking how to add your command to a linux *distribution* (e.g. Gentoo), that's beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 6):

Any executable file placed in a directory that is in the PATH (shell) variable will be a Unix command.

Answer (score 2):

1. Write your code using `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` in order to allow executing it from the command line and pipe its output
2. Parse command line arguments and use them (if you need)
3. Compile the binary
4. Locate in any directory in the PATH (e.g. /usr/sbin)